# How can I set a jquery var to be another jquery ajax functions callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sorry for my terms incase they are incorrect, but I have a php function that I am going to interop with ajax so I can use a php function to get a value for a jquery variable.

So now I am just at the point where I have received the ajax callback and would like to set the jquery variable to the response value I got back. Here is my code as an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('body').videoBG({
        position:"fixed",
        zIndex:0,
        mp4:'', //This is where I want to use the ajax response value 
        opacity:1,
    });

})

       jQuery.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "index.php",
            data    : { 
                        request    : "getvideo_Action"
                      },
            success : function(response) {
                                   alert(response);
                //Do my response stuff
                            }
        });
```

So basically what I want to do is set the 'Mp4' var(or is it property?) with the value that I get from the response. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to move the code that needs the response of the ajax request to inside the success of the ajax request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the entire thing inside the success function, like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {
        request: "getvideo_Action"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('body').videoBG({
            position: "fixed",
            zIndex: 0,
            mp4: response,
            opacity: 1
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma after `opacity: 1` that needs to be removed or else IE will have issues... Other than that, this is the correct solution.

Comment: Removed the comma. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I didn't think I would be able to put the whole function in there. That's great, thank you for your help. It is very much appreciated. :)